# Python3 batch rename

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-rename

I'm new in python and trying to make script, which renames all files in directory by this pattern `ShowName + SeasonNumber + EpisodeNumber`
This script gets filename as `argv[1]` and directory as `argv[2]`. Then in `find_needed_parts` it parses string and returns number of seasone, episode and show name. But this script is droping with such traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usrname/Documents/renameFiles/main.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/usrname/Documents/renameFiles/main.py", line 35, in main
    os.rename(pathAndFilename, os.path.join(dir, rename_name))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/posixpath.py", line 89, in join
    genericpath._check_arg_types('join', a, *p)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/genericpath.py", line 143, in _check_arg_types
    (funcname, s.__class__.__name__)) from None
TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

And here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3


import glob
import os
import sys
import re


def find_needed_parts(filename):
    ep_reg = re.search("(E|e)(\d+)", filename)
    if ep_reg:
        found_ep = ep_reg.group(2)
    s_reg = re.search("(S|s)(\d+)", filename)
    if s_reg:
        found_s = s_reg.group(2)
    ext_reg = re.search("\.(\w+)", filename)
    if ext_reg:
        ext = ext_reg.group(1)
    body_reg = re.search("((^(.*?)([^E0-9])+)|(^(.*?)([^e0-9])))", filename)
    if body_reg:
        body = body_reg.group(1)
    return body, found_ep, found_s, ext


def main():
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    direct = sys.argv[2]
    body, ep, s, ext = find_needed_parts(filename)
    pattern = "*." + ext

    for pathAndFilename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(direct, pattern)):
        title, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pathAndFilename))
        ep = int(ep) + 1  # type: int
        rename_name = str(body + 'S' + s + 'E' + str(ep) + '.' + ext)
        os.rename(pathAndFilename, os.path.join(dir, rename_name))


main()
```

**UPD1**.
here are the params

```
argv[1] = abcd E01 S09 ockoeko ko k.avi
argv[2] = .
```

Comment: What is the value of `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` where this fails? Print the values for `dir` and `rename_name` in the for loop before the line where you use `os.path.join()` and you'll most likely find what's causing your problem. One of those two do not have a string value.

Comment: @AbhinavSood updated post

Comment: `str(body + 'S' + 'E' + str(ep) + '.' + ext)` looks redundant when you can just concatenate strings like `body + 'SE' + str(ep) + '.' + ext`

Comment: @AzatIbrakov its typo, in original it must be like         `rename_name = str(body + 'S' + s + 'E' + str(ep) + '.' + ext)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the main problem is in the statement

```
os.rename(pathAndFilename, os.path.join(dir, rename_name))
```

where you are using [`dir` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir), when you've probably meant

```
os.rename(pathAndFilename, os.path.join(direct, rename_name))
```